# Method default params with nil passed in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
def foo(a=3, b=6)
  puts a+b
end
```

But I call it like this:

```
foo(params[:a], params[:b])
```

This is fine if the params are there but if they are not and it gets called with:

```
foo(nil,nil)
```

then the default values of 3 and 6 are not set and it throws an error of undef method '+' for nil class

My question is if there is a way to set defaults for a method even if nil is passed into the method. So if the user tells you nil, you say 'Screw you man!' and give him 3 anyways.

This is not a good idea, i realize, but I am just curious.

Comment: Why don't you test inside your method for nil values? `puts a+b unless a.nil? || b.nil?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using defaults in the method signature, you can use the `||=` compound assignment operator to assign a value only when a variable evaluates to nil or false in a Boolean context, as it will when it's unset. For example:

```
def foo a, b
  a ||= 3
  b ||= 6
  puts a + b
end
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I was just wondering if there was a rubyism for this that I was missing.

Comment: This will crash with an `ArgumentError` when `foo` is called with no argument. I think you should define `foo` as `foo(a=nil, b=nil)` to retain the default parameters behavior.

Comment: This will *not* "assign a value if `a` or `b` are `nil` or unset". It will assign a value if `a` or `b` are `nil` or `false` or unset.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I clarified the wording to make the nature of the Boolean evaluation more explicit.

Comment: @toro2k That's bike-shedding, and won't buy the OP anything with positional arguments because of the way he's calling the function using elements from the params hash. Splat arguments, keyword arguments, and option hashes are all possible alternatives, but they are outside the scope of the original question. Also, an ArgumentError is useful for determining when a caller has broken the contract, and is a good fit for this use case. YMMV.